# Horizontal scrollView inside vertical scrollView is not working using swift

Tags: swift

Horizontal scrollView inside vertical scrollView is not working using swift

**CODE:**

```
 scrollView_vertical.contentSize = CGSizeMake(700, 3000)
 scrollView_vertical.scrollEnabled = true

 scrollView_horizontal.contentSize = CGSizeMake( CGFloat(width), 0)
 scrollView_horizontal.scrollEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your horizontal scroll view has a content size height of 0 thats why. Your code should hopefully work if you set the height to something greater than 0.